# How to clear text inside VENToken?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have used `VENTokenField` [github](http://github.com/venmo/VENTokenField/tree/master/VENTokenField) library for recipients email. Now the user enter the email and its separated by commas(,). Everything works fine. My question is how to clear the text when user press the submit button.

1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/faf7F.jpg

2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6XSJ.jpg

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *inviteFriendNames;
self.inviteFriendNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

#pragma mark - VENTokenFieldDataSource

- (NSString *)tokenField:(VENTokenField *)tokenField titleForTokenAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (self.inviteFriendNames.count > index) {
        return self.inviteFriendNames[index];
    }
    return @"";
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfTokensInTokenField:(VENTokenField *)tokenField
{
    return self.inviteFriendNames.count;
}


#pragma mark - VENTokenFieldDelegate

- (void)tokenField:(VENTokenField *)tokenField didEnterText:(NSString *)text
{

    if (![self.inviteFriendNames containsObject:text]) {
        self.inviteFriendNames = (NSMutableArray*)[self.inviteFriendNames arrayByAddingObject:text];
        [self chosenContactsHasChanged];
    }

    return;
}

- (void)tokenField:(VENTokenField *)tokenField didDeleteTokenAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

    if (self.inviteFriendNames.count > index) {

        NSMutableArray *mutable = [self.inviteFriendNames mutableCopy];
        [mutable removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        self.inviteFriendNames = mutable;

        [self chosenContactsHasChanged];
    }

    self.tokenField.placeholderText = NSLocalizedString(@"Email", nil);
    [self chosenContactsHasChanged];
}

- (void)tokenField:(VENTokenField *)tokenField didChangeText:(NSString *)text
{
   if ([text hasSuffix:@" "]) {
        // Trim off the comma
        text = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"  "]];
        [self tokenField:tokenField didEnterText:text];

    } else {

        return;
    }
}


- (void)updateContactTokenFieldHeightConstraint
{
    CGFloat heightOfTokens = self.tokenField.tokenScrollViewHeight + tokenFieldHeightPadding;
    CGFloat newHeight = MAX(tokenFieldMinHeight, heightOfTokens);
    self.tokenFieldHeight.constant = newHeight;
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}


- (void)chosenContactsHasChanged
{
    [self.tokenField reloadData];
    [self updateContactTokenFieldHeightConstraint];
}
```

## pragma mark - UIButton Action

```
-(IBAction)inviteButtonAction:(id)sender{


    [self endEditing:YES];

    if (self.inviteFriendNames.count == 0) {

        [[PCAlertUtility sharedInstance]showOkAlertWithTitle:nil description:@"Please enter the mail id." completion:nil];
    }else{

        NSString *senderName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[APPDELEGATE.defaults valueForKey:@"firstName"],[APPDELEGATE.defaults valueForKey:@"lastName"]];

        NSDictionary *sendData = @{@"name":senderName,@"emails":inviteFriendNames};

        [self.inviteVC sendInviationAPI:INVITE_FRIENDS withParameter:sendData];

    }
}
```

## pragma mark - To invitation

```
-(void)sendInviationAPI:(NSString *)url withParameter:(NSDictionary *)parameters{

    // To Check Network Available or Unavailable
    if (![PCCommonUtility checkForNetwork]) {

        [[PCAlertUtility sharedInstance]showOkAlertWithTitle:[LocalizedStrings warning] description:[LocalizedStrings networkFailure] completion:nil];

    }else{

        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

        // To Check Access token is null or empty
        if ([APPDELEGATE.defaults valueForKey:CURRENT_TOKEN] && ![[APPDELEGATE.defaults valueForKey:CURRENT_TOKEN]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {

            [PCAPIUtility getResponseFromAPI:url withParameters:parameters withSuccess:^(NSMutableArray *responseData, NSString *success) {

                DLog(@"InviteSuccess:%@",responseData);

                NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[responseData valueForKey:@"status"]];
                NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[responseData valueForKey:@"message"]]

if ([status isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                    [[PCAlertUtility sharedInstance]showOkAlertWithTitle:nil description:message completion:^(BOOL confirm) {
                        if (!confirm) {


                            [self.inviteView.inviteFriendNames removeAllObjects];
                            [self.inviteView.tokenField reloadData];

                        }
                    }];
                }else{

                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                    [[PCAlertUtility sharedInstance]showOkAlertWithTitle:nil description:message completion:nil];
                }

            } orFailure:^(NSError *error) {

                DLog(@"InviteFailure:%@",error.description);
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                [[PCAlertUtility sharedInstance]showOkAlertWithTitle:nil description:[LocalizedStrings networkFailure] completion:nil];
            }];

        }else{

            NSLog(@"Access Token is Empty");
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: inputTextField.text = @"";

Comment: https://github.com/venmo/VENTokenField/tree/master/VENTokenField you are using this library so just write one line when you alert show and its show clear text.

Comment: I also try this, but it not work

Comment: try my answer and tell me its working or not ?

Answer (score 0):

**In ViewController class,**

.h

```
@protocol DelegateMethod <NSObject>

-(void)removeArray;

@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <DelegateMethod> delegate;

@end
```

.m

```
-(void)sendInviationAPI:(NSString *)url withParameter:(NSDictionary *)parameters{

    // To Check Network Available or Unavailable
    if (![PCCommonUtility checkForNetwork]) {

        [[PCAlertUtility sharedInstance]showOkAlertWithTitle:[LocalizedStrings warning] description:[LocalizedStrings networkFailure] completion:nil];

    }else{

        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

        // To Check Access token is null or empty
        if ([APPDELEGATE.defaults valueForKey:CURRENT_TOKEN] && ![[APPDELEGATE.defaults valueForKey:CURRENT_TOKEN]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {

            [PCAPIUtility getResponseFromAPI:url withParameters:parameters withSuccess:^(NSMutableArray *responseData, NSString *success) {

                DLog(@"InviteSuccess:%@",responseData);

                NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[responseData valueForKey:@"status"]];
                NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[responseData valueForKey:@"message"]]

    if ([status isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                    [[PCAlertUtility sharedInstance]showOkAlertWithTitle:nil description:message completion:^(BOOL confirm) {
                        if (!confirm) {

                            [self.delegate removeArray];

                        }
                    }];
                }else{

                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                    [[PCAlertUtility sharedInstance]showOkAlertWithTitle:nil description:message completion:nil];
                }

            } orFailure:^(NSError *error) {

                DLog(@"InviteFailure:%@",error.description);
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                [[PCAlertUtility sharedInstance]showOkAlertWithTitle:nil description:[LocalizedStrings networkFailure] completion:nil];
            }];

        }else{

            NSLog(@"Access Token is Empty");
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

**In View class**

**Invite Button Action**

```
-(IBAction)inviteButtonAction:(id)sender{

    [self endEditing:YES];

    if (self.inviteFriendNames.count == 0) {

        [[PCAlertUtility sharedInstance]showOkAlertWithTitle:nil description:@"Please enter the mail id." completion:nil];
    }else{

        NSString *senderName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[APPDELEGATE.defaults valueForKey:@"firstName"],[APPDELEGATE.defaults valueForKey:@"lastName"]];

        NSDictionary *sendData = @{@"name":senderName,@"emails":inviteFriendNames};
        [self.inviteVC setDelegate:self];
        [self.inviteVC sendInviationAPI:INVITE_FRIENDS withParameter:sendData];

    }
}

-(void)removeArray {

    [self.inviteFriendNames removeAllObjects];
    [self.tokenField reloadData];

}
```

Comment: I got exception to remove all objects from array

Comment: 'removeAllObjects' after calling the invite API service. Don't remove at first and send an empty array to your server.

Comment: I send value to API and got successful response after that i removeAllObjects

Comment: Still you are facing issues?

Comment: yes still i am facing this issue, i have updated my code. please check

Comment: -(void)sendInviationAPI:(NSString *)url withParameter:(NSDictionary *)parameters --> Is this function in same class or different class?

Comment: This separate method used in view controller class, my mutable array used in View class

Comment: Then do like this pass a delegate from viewcontroller class to view class. In that delegate method removeallObjects and reloadData.

Comment: could you please share code how to removeAllObjects using delegate method

Comment: No changes, still i got exception in removeAllobjects

Comment: If you don't mind please share your code in dropbox i will fix it.

Comment: I found issue and fixed it. It is because of self.inviteFriendNames = (NSMutableArray*)[self.inviteFriendNames arrayByAddingObject:text];. Thanks for your help